# Convert date in excel using regex

Tags: regex, excel

How do i represent 5-Apr in a general way using regex?
My goal is to convert 5-Apr to Apr/05 in excel.
I am currently using the Kutools and the SeoTools

Comment: You didn't ask this, but in Excel itself, if 5-Apr is a "real date" (e.g. a serial number formatted as a date), you can convert it with formatting; either within the cell or within a text function:  =TEXT(A1,"mmm/dd")

Comment: even better thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regexp would be /([0-3]?[0-9])-/ to replace with \2-\1

To have a zero for days < 10, apply the regexp to "0" concatened with your date string...